# How does one calculate $W_\mu W^\mu$ on one-particle state $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ and the transformed state $U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I am reading Sec. 2.5 of Weinberg's Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume I. It talks about the classification of relativistic one-particle states according to their transformation under the Poincare group. Since the states of a particle of a specific type are assumed to be components of irreducible representations of the Poincare group, we expect that these states will be indexed by a fixed value of $P_\mu P^\mu$. This is proved easily by acting the operator $P_\mu P^\mu$ on the states $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$. Let me write a few trivial steps.

Since $P^\mu\Psi_{p,\sigma}= p^\mu\Psi_{p,\sigma}$, where the lowercase $p^\mu$ is the eigenvalue of $P^\mu$, we have, $$P_\mu P^\mu \Psi_{p,\sigma}=\eta_{\mu\nu}P^\mu P^\nu \Psi_{p,\sigma}= p_\mu p^\mu\Psi_{p,\sigma}=m^2\Psi_{p,\sigma}$$ where in the last equality I've used that on one-particle states $p^\mu=(E,\vec{p})$ and $p_\mu p^\mu=E^2-\vec{p}^2=m^2$. Now, one can see that Lorentz transformation cannot change the eigenvalue of $P_\mu P^\mu$. Since (Weinberg 2.5.2) $$P^\mu \left[U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}\right]=(\Lambda p)^\mu\left[U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}\right],$$ we have,

$$P_\mu P^\mu\left[U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}\right] = (\Lambda p)_\mu(\Lambda p)^\mu \left[U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}\right] = m^2\left[U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}\right]$$

where in the last step we have used $$(\Lambda p)_\mu(\Lambda p)^\mu=\Lambda^{~\nu}_{\mu}\Lambda^{\mu}_{~\rho}p_\nu p^\rho=\delta^{\nu}_{\rho}p_\nu p^\rho=p_\nu p^\nu=m^2.$$ Weinberg's method of classification is exclusively based on classes having a fixed value of $P_\mu P^\mu$ and of fixed ${\rm sgn}~p^0$.

---

However, we also know that the Poincare group has another Casimir, $W_\mu W^\mu$  where $W_\mu=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{\mu\nu\sigma\rho}P^\nu J^{\sigma\rho}$. We expect that these irreps will also be indexed by fixed values $W_\mu W^\mu$.

How does one explicitly calculate $W_\mu W^\mu$, on the one-particle state $\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ and the transformed state $U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}$ given by Eq.(2.5.23)
$$U(\Lambda)\Psi_{p,\sigma}=\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda p^0}{p^0}}\sum_{\sigma^\prime}D_{\sigma^\prime\sigma}^{(j)}\left( W(\Lambda,p)\right)\Psi_{\Lambda o,\sigma^\prime},$$
and show that they share the same eigenvalue for $W_\mu W^\mu$?